# CPU at 50%, Yet IIS/ASP.net Requests still being queued

Tags: iis, asp.net

We have a (VMWare) VM, which when load testing, appears to start queueing requests at 120 users.

The CPU doesn't appear to hit over 70%, so I'm struggling to see why it would be failing to process the requests?

CPU Time is shown bottom left in Red
[image: CPU Graph]

Comment: What about disc load? I can see a scenario that uses up all standard allocated threads but not all cpu because it has another bottleneck - and IO is the most likely culprit.

Comment: Logically: because the app isn't cpu bound. Check where the time is going when the response time is 10s.

Comment: Already checked the Disk IO, it was around 1~2%, there was an issue with Page Faults - but I can't appear to re-create it.

Answer (score 2):

CPU isn't the only bottleneck for processing requests. All depends on what your application is doing. If you're doing a lot of IO bound work, that could be a bigger factor than CPU.

ASP.net has a limited number threads in it's ThreadPool, so if they're all busy, they'll start to queue. Check [this piece](http://blog.leansentry.com/2013/07/all-about-iis-asp-net-request-queues/) for some tips on request queuing.

Are you doing lots of sql inserts/updates per request? Get some timings on those, with Glimpse even. Too many of those and they hold up threads/requests waiting for responses.

Are you calling out to some 3rd party api's? Those hold up threads/requests waiting and there are limitations on how many simultaneous connections are allowed.

What does the application do for each user? are you retrieving 1000+ records?

Check this [MS Connect support article](http://support2.microsoft.com/?id=821268#tocHeadRef), there are a good number of IIS configuration options that might help you, if you haven't tweaked those already.

Again, this is with out knowing what your application does and how.